# Prevent two div elements from being visible at one time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I prevent both "inner" divs from being visible at the same time. Say if one is visible, and the other is called, the one currently active should slideUp before the new one slidesDown.

**HTML:**

```
            <div class="redirectWrap">
                <a id="redirectDefault" class="redirectOuter" href="#">
                    <h4>Default URL</h4>
                    <span>test.com/tctc91</h4>
                </a>
                <a id="redirectCustom" class="redirectOuter" href="#">
                    <h4>Custom URL</h4>
                    <span>m.tomchristian.co.uk</h4>
                </a>
                <div class="redirectDefaultInner redirectBox hide">
                    test
                </div>
                <div class="redirectCustomInner redirectBox hide">
                    test
                </div>                  
            </div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.redirectOuter').click(function() { 
    $(this).parent().find('.'+$(this).attr('id')+'Inner').slideUp('fast'); 
    return false;
});

$('.redirectOuter').click(function(e){  
    var inner = $(this).parent().find('.'+$(this).attr('id')+'Inner');
    if(!inner.is(":visible")) { 
        inner.stop().slideDown('fast');
    }
    e.stopPropagation();        
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**
Updated your code to make it work as you wanted,

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/b5pT4/2/)

```
var $redirectBoxes = $('.redirectBox');
$('.redirectOuter').click(function(e){  
    var inner = $(this).parent().find('.'+$(this).attr('id')+'Inner');
    if(inner.is(":visible")) {
        $(this).parent().find('.'+$(this).attr('id')+'Inner').slideUp('fast');
    } else {
        $redirectBoxes.not(inner).slideUp('fast');
        inner.stop().slideDown('fast');
    }
    e.stopPropagation();        
});
```

---

I think jQuery [accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) is what you need.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/E4ppk/2/)

With some changes to your markup,

```
<div class="redirectWrap">
   <h4><a id="redirectDefault" class="redirectOuter" href="#">
        Default URL
        <span>test.com/tctc91</span>
    </a><h4>
    <div class="redirectDefaultInner redirectBox hide">
          test
    </div>
    <h4><a id="redirectCustom" class="redirectOuter" href="#">
        Custom URL
        <span>m.tomchristian.co.uk</span></a>
    </h4>
    <div class="redirectCustomInner redirectBox hide">
         test
    </div>                  
 </div>
```

And JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('.redirectWrap').accordion();
});
```

Comment: is it not a bit overkill using jQuery UI just for this one tiny thing?

Comment: @tctc91 Depends, however If you are not using jQuery UI and just want to use accordion.. you can still do so by doing a custom build which will just give you the necessary library that you need. But think about all the other nice features you get along with this.. and the browser compatibility/enhancements.

Comment: @tctc91 Check my updated post. Modified your code to work as you wanted. http://jsfiddle.net/skram/b5pT4/2/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [jQuery Accordion](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion)

Comment: is it not a bit overkill using jQuery UI just for this one tiny thing?

Comment: I don't know.  You tell me.  How's it working for you so far? :P

Comment: true, but I would imagine there's a simpler method of solving this than having to include an entire new UI framework into my site. I just can't think of any solution right now.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$('.redirectOuter').click(function() {
    var active =$(this).parent().find('.redirectBox:visible');
    var toBeActivated =$(this).parent().find('.'+$(this).attr('id')+'Inner');
    $(active).slideUp('fast');
    if($(active)[0]===$(toBeActivated)[0]){
       return;
      }
    $(toBeActivated).slideDown('fast'); 
    return false;
 });
```

Comment: That works nicely. Although it appears that the animations are occuring before the previous one has even finished making it look a bit odd. Is there anyway to make it wait for the animation to completely finish before starting the new one?